# Duck typing with type provider instances

Tags: f#, type-providers, duck-typing

I am writing an F# script to operate on tables in a database. All of the tables have a `Guid Id` property. I want to make use of duck typing to refer to this ID in several places.

Take for example this function:

```
let inline getAllIds<'a when 'a : (member Id : Guid with get)
                        and 'a : not struct> (table : Table<'a>) =
    table |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Id)
```

I had hoped that the `when 'a : (member Id : Guid with get)` constraint would allow me to use the `Id` property on a table record, but I get a type inference error ('a type annotation may be needed' etc).

Furthermore, if I try to pass in a table that doesn't have a `Guid Id` property to the function, it correctly complains that it does not support the operator `get_Id`. This seems to indicate to me that I have got the syntax right but might need an additional constraint somewhere. Is what I want to do possible?

(I know that I can just pass a function into this function to retrieve the ID... but where's the fun in that?!)

Comment: "pass a **fun**ction into this **fun**ction" Found it.

Comment: ...sigh, have a +1 :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll maintain that this is a duplicate, but here's the exact code you need to get going:

```
let inline getAllIds< ^a when ^a : not struct> (table : Table< ^a>) =
    table |> Seq.map (fun x -> (^a : (member Id : Guid with get) x))
```

Alternatively, the following syntax can be used instead:

```
let inline getAllIds< ^a when ^a : not struct> (table : Table< ^a>) =
    table |> Seq.map (fun x -> (^a : (member get_Id : unit -> Guid) x))
```

IIRC, the latter syntax is *required* when using a pre-3.0 F# compiler.

Comment: Thanks!  You're right,  it's a duplicate question of the one you linked in a comment